# MATLAB - Image doesn't display correctly when using global variable

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, global-variables

I'm trying to use a global variable to store an image loaded from a .tif file. However, when I display the image, the brightness/contrast become skewed. When I remove the global declaration, the images load just fine, however that prevents me from using it in my other functions, which are used to edit/save.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
global rgbI %<----Change this from global to not global

fname = 'test.tif';
info = imfinfo(fname);
num_images = numel(info);

for k = 1:num_images
    I(:,:,k) = imread(fname, k);
    rgbI(:,:,:,k) = repmat(I(:,:,k),[1 1 3]);
end

imshow(rgbI(:,:,:,150))
```

I'm using this in a MATLAB GUI (written using GUIDE), along with several other functions which are attached to various buttons etc. However, this issue shows up even in just this little script, outside of the GUI.

Here are the resulting images that I get:

## Image #1

[image: blah]

## Image #2

[image: blah]

Any suggestions/help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Has the value range been changed before / after setting `rgbI` to be global?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to declare the variable as global in all the function that need them.

Another way is to guidata. Reference for it is here:[guidata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)